# How can you set the color of Incanter's add-lines?

Tags: clojure, incanter

When calling the `add-lines` function from the Clojure library Incanter, the added lines will use every color in the rainbow. However, I want every added line to be black. Figuring out how to do this has proven remarkably tricky. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICT you have to explicitly set display options for each `add-lines` call because they internally create separate datasets.

```
(doto (xy-plot [1 2 3 4] [10 20 5 35])
  (add-lines [1 2 3 4] [20 5 30 15])
  (add-lines [1 2 3 4] [5 30 -1 20])
  ;; set color for each line dataset
  (set-stroke-color java.awt.Color/black :dataset 0)
  (set-stroke-color java.awt.Color/black :dataset 1)
  (set-stroke-color java.awt.Color/black :dataset 2)
  (view))
```

[image]

Relevant GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/incanter/incanter/issues/131).